# Play 1.2.4 CRUD: Manipulating the UI based on model

Tags: java, web-applications, playframework, crud, playframework-1.x

I am using crud module in Play 1.2.4 for user role management.

In the model (which is mapped with the Entity), I am having a few fields such as Record Create Timestamp etc which I don't want to be displayed in the UI. By default, it is getting displayed. I cant remove these fields also from the Entity since I need to perform some operations on these.

Kindly let me know how to remove some of the fields from UI which are preent in the Entity model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the template used by CRUD, for your model.

First, override the template : `play crud:ov Roles\blank.html` (assuming Roles is your CRUD Controller)
then modify it :

search `#{crud.form fields:[field1', 'field2', 'field3' ]/}` and remove `field2`, for example, if you don't want to display it.

Comment: +1 for the the quick reply, it worked exactly the way I wanted. Tell me another thing related to this: If I want to change the textbox to a drop-down, then how to proceed with that? We have a requirement like we need to change one of the textbox to dropdown since the users won't understand the DB values getting saved in the backend...hence the plan is to display the text in a dropdown and at the backend send the values to the DB. Kindly let me know how to achieve this. Thanks for the reply again...

Comment: Thanks for the reply...1 last thing: if I need to make a text field as read only then also do I need to use the crud.custom tag? Or, there is some property which can make the textbox as read only?

Answer (score 0):

If you annotate a field with `@CRUD.Hidden`it won't display in the UI.

CRUD shows `enum` types as dropdown.